# Multiple Buttons Tkinter - location on canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have found some code (complements of stack-overflow) that will make multiple buttons on a canvas. 
What i would like to learn is how to position theses multiple buttons anywhere on the canvas for example button 1 button 2 button 3 etc and have them in the middle of the canvas. Also if i had say 50 buttons how could i have them in a 10 x 5 format ?

```
  from tkinter import *
  from tkinter import ttk
  from functools import partial

  root = Tk()
  root.title('test')

  mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding='1')
  mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

  root.resizable(False, False)                 
  root.geometry('800x400')

  items = [
      {
          'name' : '1',
          'text' : '0000',
      },{
          'name' : '2',
          'text' : '0020',
      },{
          'name' : '3',
          'text' : '0040',
      },
  ]

  rcount = 1 

  for rcount, item in enumerate(items, start=1): 
     ttk.Button(mainframe, text=item['text'], 
  command=partial(print,item['text'])).grid(column=1, row=rcount, sticky=W)

  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your first step should be to work through a tkinter tutorial. Stackoverflow isn't intended to be a free coding service.

Comment: Sorry Bryan, it's been that way since its inception!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put widgets on a canvas with `create_window()` which takes x & y coordinates, height, width and widget reference (and anchor).

See example below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('800x400')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # Which column should expand with window
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # Which row should expand with window

items = [{'name' : '1', 'text' : '0000', 'x': 0, 'y': 0},
         {'name' : '2', 'text' : '0020', 'x': 55, 'y': 150},
         {'name' : '3', 'text' : '0040', 'x': 600, 'y': 200}]

canvas = Canvas(root, bg='khaki')   # To see where canvas is
canvas.grid(sticky=NSEW)

for item in items:
    widget = ttk.Button(root, text=item['text'],
                        command=partial(print,item['text']))
    # Place widget on canvas with: create_window
    canvas.create_window(item['x'], item['y'], anchor=NW, 
                         height=25, width=70, window=widget)

root.mainloop()
```

To get buttons in a 10 x 5 format, just use nested for-loops.

```
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(5):
        text = str(x) + ' x ' + str(y)
        widget = ttk.Button(root, text=text,
                            command=partial(print,text))
        # Place widget on canvas with: create_window
        canvas.create_window(10+75*x, 10+30*y, anchor=NW, 
                             height=25, width=70, window=widget)
```

The easiest way to name all buttons is probably to make a dictionary associating the name with the position:

```
text_dict = {'0 x 0': '0000',
             '1 x 0': '0020'
             # etc, etc.
             }
```

and then use the dict in setting the button text:

```
text = text_dict[str(x) + ' x ' + str(y)]
```

Comment: Thank you !!! Both pieces of code work really well - For the nested loop code , how do i replace the text = str(x) + 'x' + str(y) with the items in a dictionary thus each button text would would be  0000  0020  0040  etc

Comment: Thank you - i know understand how the dictionary key relates to the values and how i can add a range of buttons using these values